# execution failed for task ':processDebugResources

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

[image]

Once i run the ionic cordova run android it gives me this kind of error. Ive been reinstalling my node, npm and android studio but still gives me this kind of error. I also read errors posted similar to this and been trying to do what their solution is but i cant seem to find the solution.

Comment: ive been finding solution for days already. i hope someone can help me ::(

Comment: ive been doing a fresh start project and inserted my files but sstil gives me the same kind of error :(((((((